# How to add details with a file in android

Tags: android, file, metadata

I want to add some additional information with a file in android.For example name, type,size are already associated with a file but i want to add another attribute like Company with its value.Is it possible??

For more clarification: I want to develop an app that will take a file as input and add some additional properties with it like company:"company name".Then wherever i send this file user will be able to see this property in its details section with other built in properties.

Comment: http://www-inf.int-evry.fr/cours/java/javatutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html

Comment: not in java. The only way is probably jni with linux syscall

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link which helps you to set the owner of the file

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setOwner-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipal-

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Config Reader i used:

```
public class ConfigReader {
private static ConfigReader instance = new ConfigReader();
private Properties properties;


ConfigReader() {

}   


public void initializeFramework() throws IOException {
    this.properties = loadProperties(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/YourApp/Settings.prop");
    }   


public Properties getProperties() {
    return properties;
}

public Properties loadProperties(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    File propertiescheck = new File (path);
    if (!propertiescheck.exists()){
        createDefaultProperties(path);
    }
    BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
    properties.load(stream);        
    return properties;
}



private void createDefaultProperties(String path) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    File creator = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/YourApp/");
    creator.mkdirs();
    FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(path, true);
    properties.setProperty("size","100");
            properties.setProperty("type","Company");
    properties.store(writer, "These are Default things");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}


public ConfigReader getInstance() {
    return instance;
    }
```

}

It Looks for a Settings.prop File in /YourApp/ and reads the values. If it doesnt find the File, it creates an own. I suggest you let it create one, and look at the Format first, before editing the file.

Somewhere else you could then read out the read Properties file as follows:

```
   ConfigReader configReader = new ConfigReader();
   configReader.getInstance().initializeFramework();
   String size= configReader.getInstance().getProperties().getProperty("size", "50").toString();
```

Note that the "50" isgetting returned, when either the Property file isnt found or created, or the "size" value hasnt been defined in the Properties file. And in case you Need the size as an Integer you Need to parse it like this

```
Integer.parseInt(YourString);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is good option but its storing the information in another file. My requirement is wherever i send my file people will be able to see the information i added in it.

Comment: then you could read the Properties file and Display it in the app... i think :D i dont quiet understand your issue here. Display the Properties file somewhere, and make 2 TextViews where the User can dynamically add Properties :D but like i said i am not quiet sure what you want to achieve

Comment: Actually i want to develop an app that will take a file as input and add some additional properties with it like company:"company name".Then wherever i send this file user will be able to see this property in its details section with other built in properties.

Comment: so basically you want to add a flag to the file itself? hmm... i guess you either have to add some lines to the file itself, or save it as a Folder and add the Propertyfile named above in this Folder, like a README.txt in modern games, and then the Person you would send the file to, would Need to have some sort of applicaiton that again reads out your property file

Comment: in case you want to see the first option i have a solution for that as well. There will be lines at the End of the file you sent

Comment: Saving as a folder will spoil the purpose.I just want to add my own property:value pair in the detail section of a file. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: so i guess the solution with the appended Information isnt accepltable either?

Comment: what if the file is a video or audio or image file. How do we add lines at the end of these files??

Comment: ok you beat me :D i have no idea :P especially not in android. in Windows there might have been a possibility but like this i have no idea :P only Thing that Comes to my mind is, to write some Information into the file Name but already sounds bad :D especially if you want to add loads of informaitions